# Closed graph theorem for operator topologies - Do operator topologies yield Fréchet spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, locally-convex-spaces, closed-graph

Consider the SOT and WOT operator topologies on $B(H)$, the bounded operators on a hilbert space $H$. I'm interested in the properties of the topological vector spaces induces on $B(H)$. Are they Fréchet? Or does there exist a closed graph theorem for mappings between these spaces?

This question came up when looking for a question to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129061/homomorphism-between-concrete-von-neumann-algebras-is-strong-strong-continuous) and hoping to apply the argument I developed in [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131594/if-locally-convex-topologies-exhibit-the-same-dual-spaces-do-they-exhibit-the-s) to solve the first one. Both questions have only been answered partially and I'm hoping to gain more insight on the matter by opening a new post asking a more specific question.

Comment: They are not Frechet: Otherwise the  identity map $(B(H),SOT) \to (B(H),$operator norm$)$ would be continuous due to the closed graph theorem. By the same reason, they are not ultrabornological.

Comment: You should be able to show it is not first countable, the same way one does for the weak topology on $H$.