# Do all *-isomorphisms between von Neumann algebras preserve strong operator topology?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Do all $*$-isomorphisms between von Neumann algebras preserve the strong operator topology?

Seems clearly true for $*$-isomorphisms with a unitary implementation, but I don't see the answer for other cases ... perhaps there is an easy argument from the fact that von Neumann algebras are closed in this topology, but I've spent a while looking for one and don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $M$ to be any II$_1$-factor. Let $\pi:M\to B(H)$ be an irreducible representation (it exists because you can do GNS of a pure state). As $M$ is simple (as a C$^*$-algebra!), $\pi$ is injective. And $\pi(M)$ is dense in $B(H)$, but it cannot be everything.

So $\pi:M\to\pi(M)$ is a $*$-isomorphism that does not preserve the sot/wot/ultrasot/ultrawot topologies.

As mentioned in the comments,  if $M\subset B(H)$ and $N\subset B(K)$ are von Neumann algebras (in the usual "double commutant" sense) then a $*$-isomorphism $\pi:M\to N$ is sot-continuous on bounded sets by passing through normality.

Comment: But in this case $\pi$ is not a $\ast$-isomorphism since it is not surjective.

Comment: I am also not convinced since $\ast$-homomorphism must preserve the suprema of ascending families of projections and that will imply normality for $\pi$. Perhaps I am confused about that.

Comment: @Adrián: of course, I can take $\pi(M)$ to be the codomain. And you seem to have a misunderstanding of the equivalence normal $\iff$ sot-continuous (and you need selfadjoints, not just projections). The equivalence is true, **if** you are doing it in a von Neumann algebra. Unless you claim that every monotone-complete C$^*$-algebra is a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that.

Comment: No problem. I have mixed feelings about the fact that von Neumann algebras are always considered represented. On the one hand, it makes a lot of sense because it is how you would usually use them. But, on the other hand, because this is usually not really considered in textbooks, together with AW$^*$-algebras becoming unfashionable a few decades ago, there is little knowledge about all this (including me).

Comment: Thanks for this & also for answer to an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129061/homomorphism-between-concrete-von-neumann-algebras-is-sot-sot-continuous-iff-i?rq=1), which just led me to 7.1.16 of Kadison/Ringrose: "$*$ isomorphisms between von Neumann algebras are weak- and strong-operator homeomorphisms **on bounded sets**," which is the main result I was looking for. I am probably missing some key knowledge to understand your counterexample though. If $\pi(M)$ is a vN algebra that's dense in $B(H)$, musn't it be all of $B(H)$, since vN algebras are sot-closed?

Comment: The algebra $\pi(M)$ is C$^*$-isomorphic to a von Neumann algebra. The usual definition of von Neumann algebra is not intrinsic (as my example shows), but depends on the environment. But yes, if $M\subset B(H)$ and $N\subset B(K)$ are von Neumann algebras (in the usual "double commutant" sense) then a $*$-isomorphism $\pi:M\to N$ is sot continuous by passing through normality.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I just happened to stumble over it. Even if $M$ and $N$ are concrete von Neumann algebras, it is not true that an $\ast$-isomorphism is SOT-continuous. For example, the SOT on $B(H)\subset B(S_2(H))$ equalso the $\sigma$-SOT (as for any von Neumann algebra in standard form), but SOT and $\sigma$-SOT are different on $B(H)\subset B(H)$. What is true in this setting is that $\ast$-isomorphisms (or more generally normal cp maps) are always SOT-continuous on norm bounded sets.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Edited.